# Can glmmTMB be used without a random effect?

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I'm curious whether `glmmTMB` can be used without a random effect. Both `glmer`, `lmer`, and `lme` throw an error about lack of random effects, but `glmmTMB` runs fine. However, when I test a logistic regression using `glmmTMB` and regular `glm`, I get very different p values. Toy example below.

```
library(glmmTMB)
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly")) 

data(mtcars)
mtcars$Bin <- as.numeric(mtcars$mpg > 20) # create a binary variable

m <- glm(Bin ~ as.factor(cyl) + wt, data= mtcars, family = "binomial")
m1 <- glmmTMB(Bin ~ as.factor(cyl) + wt, data= mtcars, family = "binomial")

car:::Anova(m)
car:::Anova(m1)
```

Comment: The coefficients and anova are different because the data is too sparse for logistic regression. If you look at the coefficients, some of them are huge, which indicates (likely) unreliable model fit.

Comment: This is just a toy example. I was seeing the same issue with my actual data. I'll update the example though to make it clearer, thank you!

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing. Did you reach an answer for this? Thanks.

Comment: I just don't think it's meant to do that. If, like me, you wanted to have access to the correlation structures as well as the full glm family list, try either looking into GAMs or into INLA...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `glmmTMB` happily fits models without random effects.

As pointed out in comments, the reason you're getting (apparently) very different answers from `glm` and `glmmTMB` is that you have *complete separation* in your example: all of the cars with 4 cylinders have Bin==1 and all of those with 8 cylinders have Bin==0 (There are questions on CrossValidated and Stack Overflow about how to diagnose and deal with complete separation, but a short version is that any coefficient value with $|\beta| \gt 10$ in a logistic regression with reasonably scaled inputs is a red flag.)

```r
with(mtcars, table(Bin, cyl))
   cyl
Bin  4  6  8
  0  0  4 14
  1 11  3  0
```